# Finding a periodic function with this fundamental cycle

Tags: fourier-series, periodic-functions, trigonometric-series

I'd like to write a smooth ($C^{\infty}$), periodic function $f(x)$ with a fundamental cycle that looks like this:

[image]

I include no scale because I'm only interested in the signs of $f(x)$, $f'(x)$, and $f''(x)$, that is, I'd like the signs of the value, slope, and concavity of $f(x)$ to match those from the picture at each $x$ throughout the fundamental domain. One non-smooth answer that achieves this is

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1-\cos(x)&0\le x\text{ mod }4\pi \le2\pi\\-1+\cos(x)&2\pi\le x\text{ mod }4\pi \le4\pi\end{cases}$$

This is not smooth at multiples of $2\pi$. I imagine Fourier series may be helpful, though I'm not well-versed in them. Maybe there is some simple (finite) linear combination of sines and cosines that achieves the desired effect, and I just can't see it. Thanks!

Comment: @StinkingBishop: Close, but not quite the behavior I'm looking for at the endpoints, where the function flattens out. I do hope the answer is something this simple though...

Comment: Idk probably you could find a polynomial that does that in $[0,1]$ and is smooth when defined to be periodic but i don't know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez: Yes, I tried this (at least I think I did if I understand what you're suggesting). The polynomial would have triple roots at 0, 0.5, and 1, but when you try gluing it, the fourth derivative is not continuous at the boundaries. I guess smoothness is hard to achieve when gluing...